# Horizontally centering a character in a div is off by a pixel

Tags: css

I've tried a lot of different things such as using a px width, or em widths. I've tried nesting a span and applying variations on `text-align:center` or `margin:0 auto`.

I can get the R to center or the S to center, but I can't get them both to center with the same style. It needs to be the same style since although in this example it is fixed, in general the character will be unknown.

Increasing and decreasing font-size will also sometimes adjust which item is centered. When I zoom my browser in to 300% they both appear centered, but that obviously isn't a solution. :)

```
<style>
div { margin-bottom:10px; }

span {
  display:inline-block;
  width:16px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:20px;
}

.example2 span {
  border-radius:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="example1">
<span>R</span> <span>S</span>
</div>

<div class="example2">
<span>R</span> <span>S</span>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NrqJLX

[image: example of poor alignment]

You can see the 'S' is too far right by 1 pixel.

While I have found a ton of other stackoverflow questions that are similar, none is quite the same. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Because, unless you are using a monospace font, the character glyphs *aren't the same size*

Comment: I agree with you that the character glyphs are not the same size. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides glyph sizes, and in this case, since the space is 16px in the rectangle and 14px in the circle and the "S" is visual 7px wide, it has to be either 1px to the right (or the left), as it can't be positioned at a half pixel's position.

This will cause an issue no matter what you do, monospace or not, as some letters visual width (or height) minus the available space divided with 2, will not always create an even space on both side, hence be 1 pixel left or right (top or bottom) of the actual center.

That said, I think `flexbox` will do the best job keeping things centered, so I simply replaced `display: inline-block` with this in your existing code

```
display: inline-flex;      /* used inline-flex to keep the span side-by-side */
justify-content: center;   /* horizontal, when using row direction */
align-items: center;       /* vertical,          -  "  -           */
```

Sample snippet

```css
div {
  margin-bottom:10px; 
}

span {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:16px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin-left:20px;
}

.example2 span {
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">
<span>R</span> <span>S</span>
</div>

<div class="example2">
<span>R</span> <span>S</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The 16px width is not a requirement. Something around that size (not 144px!) is. I adjusted to 17px width with `display:inline-block` and it isn't perfect, but close enough I think. The `inline-flex` is great, except an unusually high number of IE users (8%+) so we need to hold off on using that for another year probably. ;)

Comment: @LGson , interestingly , if i remove `width:16px;` and intead apply `padding:2px 15px;` the `S` is vertically centered. does't it ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik It centered it as good as possible, there is still 1px more space below the `S` for the very same reason ... adjusting the font size +/- 1px will likely make it perfect, though this might be browser specific which makes it almost impossible ... in my experience having the extra pixel space below make it look more centered than having it above, guess the eye gets less tricked done like that

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that the center of the character is not always where you think it is. All character glyphs are not the same width in "normal" fonts/typefaces.

Unless the font is both monospace and sans-serif, the ascenders, descenders and serifs all affect the "dimensions" of the character glyphs.

For better accuracy, set the width/height/line-height in `em` and if you *really* need it to be accurate to the **exact pixel** you'll have to adjust manually.

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  font-size: 144px;
  line-height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.example2 span {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.other {
  font-family: monospace
}
```

```html
<div class="example2">
  <span>R</span>  <span>S</span>
</div>

<div class="example2 other">
  <span>R</span>  <span>S</span>
</div>
```

Comment: As mentioned, 144px makes most of the problems go away. But, your example is also not horizontally centered even with monospace. I adjusted font size to 14px and height/width/line to 1.2em http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzNbjL