# Equal padding on button not distributing equally

Tags: html, css

I was just having a small issue with applying equal padding to a button, I applied the following styles to it:

```
.btn-request-more-info {
    background: #fff;
    color: #6e2c91;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0.5 2.5em;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}
```

Now since the above doesn't work, I had to use a hack and reduce 1px from the bottom padding of the button:

```
.btn-request-more-info {
    background: #fff;
    color: #6e2c91;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 2.5em 9px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}
```

10px above and 9px below, so why is it that `0.5em` padding is not equally distributed?

P.S. to recreate the error, change the styles in the button to `padding:0.5em 2em`.

Difference in padding (I have used  ruler to show visually the difference in padding distribution).

Padding above:

[image]

Padding below:

[image]

I have had this problem many times before, but never found a solution. Why might this be happening?

Comment: You can try by applying top,right,bottom,left padding. In that keep your top and left padding value bit more compare to bottom and right.

Comment: Are we talking about the actual font characters not being in the center?

Comment: @LGSon yes , absoluty :)

Comment: If I measure them at your site they are 13px high, correct? ... which means that either the top or bottom part needs to be 1 pixel bigger since the space is 44px .... does that make sence?

Comment: Further more, the font itself is not self centered as it has internal margins to make up for big/small characters growing above/below its baseline ... does that as well make sence?

Comment: even if you apply the following to padding `0 2.5em` , u'll see that the top and bottom padding is not equal , i am asking `WHY` , i am more interested in the `WHY` part then an actually solution , which i beleive we will come to.

Comment: Just explained why

Comment: @LGSon ` the font itself is not self centered as it has internal margins to make up for big/small characters growing above/below its baseline ` hmmm ... i guess thats got me on track , interesting ! thanks .

Comment: Check this post, likely a duplicate: [horizontally-centering-a-character-in-a-div-is-off-by-a-pixel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645614/horizontally-centering-a-character-in-a-div-is-off-by-a-pixel)

Comment: @LGSon mate just caught up , thanks for your valuable inputs , let me look into this. i'll get back to you , though u've given me enuf things to think about now :D TY

Comment: @LGSon very interesting , still don't that issue is the same as mine though . here its padding , there the guys using width. (P.S. i don't ever  set fixed widths ... thats just bad :P ).

Answer (score -1):

This can be because of `line-height` property of css. If you see the `computed values`(visual representation present at the end of style tab of developer tool) from developer tool both `padding-top` and `bottom` are same. But the difference you notice is not considering the `line-height` of the text. If you hover over your element from developer tool you'll see that box surrounding the text has some space below the text. The browser while applying padding consider this to be the part of the text and applies padding only around this box.

Comment: This doesn't make up for an uneven font character height and its internal glyph sizes

Answer (score -2):

Try `line-height:normal` properties in css for button:

```
.btn-request-more-info {
    background: #fff;
    color: #6e2c91;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 2.5em 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    line-height:normal;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make up for an uneven font character height and its internal glyph sizes